# Error iterating through a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, keyerror

When I get the first and second elements of this series, it works OK, but from element 3 onwards, giving an error when I try to fetch.

```
type(X_test_raw)
Out[51]: pandas.core.series.Series

len(X_test_raw)
Out[52]: 1393

X_test_raw[0]
Out[45]: 'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'

X_test_raw[1]
Out[46]: 'Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...'

X_test_raw[2]
```

> KeyError: 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

consider the series `X_test_raw`

```
X_test_raw = pd.Series(
    ['Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...',
     'Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...',
     'PLEASE DON\'T FAIL'
    ], [0, 1, 3])
```

`X_test_raw` doesn't have an index of `2` which you are trying to reference with `X_test_raw[2]`.

Instead use `iloc`

```
X_test_raw.iloc[2]

"PLEASE DON'T FAIL"
```

You can iterate through the series with `iteritems`

```
for index_val, series_val in X_test_raw.iteritems():
    print series_val

Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...
Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
PLEASE DON'T FAIL
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no index with value `2`.

Sample:

```
X_test_raw = pd.Series([4,8,9], index=[0,4,5])

print (X_test_raw)
0    4
4    8
5    9
dtype: int64

#print (X_test_raw[2])
#KeyError: 2
```

If need third value use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (X_test_raw.iloc[2])
9
```

If need iterating only values:

```
for x in X_test_raw:
    print (x)
4
8
9
```

If need `indexes` and `values` use [`Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for idx, x in X_test_raw.iteritems():
    print (idx, x)
0 4
4 8
5 9
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to iterate sequentially through this series ?

Comment: Yes, I add solution.